# Retrieving data sequentially from firebase database using async / await not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await

I have a react.js component where I intend to pull data from two different nodes in firebase sequentially. Here's the code. But it's not working:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const publisherID = this.props.match.params.id;
  const that = this;
  const soundcasts = [];

  const publisher = await firebase.database().ref('publishers/' + publisherID).once('value');

  const soundcastsArr = Object.keys(publisher.val().soundcasts);

  console.log('soundcastsArr: ', soundcastsArr);

  let soundcast;
  for(let i = 0; i < soundcastsArr.length; i++) {
    console.log('for block called');
    soundcast = await firebase.database().ref(`soundcasts/${soundcastsArr[i]}`).once('value');
    console.log('soundcast: ', soundcast.val());
    console.log('i: ', i); 
  }
}
```

I'm able to see the console.log of `soundcastsArr`, and the first `console.log('for block called');`, but not the rest. It seems the loop stops executing at the line `soundcast = await firebase.database().ref(`soundcasts/${soundcastsArr[i]}`).once('value');`

And there's no error showing.

Here's where it gets more weird. If I add another `await` inside the for loop to retrieve data from some other node, right before retrieving from the `soundcasts` node, like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < soundcastsArr.length; i++) {
    console.log('for block called');
    const user = await firebase.database().ref(`users/reionviorfruinjkd343fsk`).once('value');
    console.log('user: ', user.val());
    soundcast = await firebase.database().ref(`soundcasts/${soundcastsArr[i]}`).once('value');
    console.log('soundcast: ', soundcast.val());
    console.log('i: ', i);
  }
```

it makes everything working and I get every `console.log` to show.

This seems rather strange to me.

Any firebase expert can shed some light on this?

---

Update: this is now working. It turned out that the `await` in the for loop did work. But for whatever reason it takes a long time to retrieve data from that particular node. Hence I wasn't seeing any console.log before the component moved on to execute other functions. Added loading indicator into component. Now everything renders fine.

Comment: change `await firebase.database()`  to `return  firebase.database()`

Comment: @gvmani Tried. Didn't work.

Comment: If you use `await`, you don't need `then`. That's the point of `await`

Comment: I'm surprised no errors were thrown. If you use `await`, use that callback argument as a variable assignment and take out the `then`. `await` should read like block code. For example, it should be `const res = await Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: @Andrew Edited the code as you suggested (see my revised post. taking out .then from await). Still no dice. And don't see any errors.

Comment: You're positive `firebase.database().ref(`soundcasts/${soundcastsArr[i]}`).once('value')` returns something meaningful?

Comment: @Andrew If that ref(...) doesn't exist, wouldn't I at least be able to get `undefined` when I do `console.log('soundcast: ', soundcast.val());`? But I don't see that console.log in the console at all. Nothing shows.

Comment: Take out the `await` in your loop and see if you can get `console.log('soundcast: ', soundcast.val())` to throw an error.

Comment: @Andrew If I take out `await` in the loop, I get the error `TypeError: soundcast.val is not a function`.

Comment: @NatashaC could you sandbox the issue so we can tinker and fix https://codesandbox.io/s/w0nvzjy218

Comment: @JoshPittman Got it to work. It turned out the `await` in the for loop did work. But for some reason it takes a long time to retrieve from that target node (3-4 seconds). I should have been more patient...

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching the concept of an array of promises incorrectly. First build the array of promises, and then use `Promise.all` on that array. Don't `await` each individual one.

```
const soundcastPromises = soundcastsArr.map((soundcast) => {
  return firebase.database().ref(`soundcasts/${soundcastsArr[i]}`).once('value')
})

const resolvedSoundcasts = await Promise.all(soundcastPromises)
```

That's to fix your use of `Promise.all`. I can't be sure as to why your query hangs.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be caused by any improper use of Promise.all or await. Please see my revised post. Though I still don't know what the problem is.